# Android - adding Views onscreen, but outside the content view

Tags: android

I'm creating a component that needs to appear above and separate from the existing UI, like sliding in from the bottom of the screen and staying anchored there, regardless of the current contentview.  I'd like it to be modular and portable, so pre-supposing a FrameLayout isn't realistic.

In looking at the source for the Dialog and PopupWindow classes, it looks like they accomplish this using the Window and WindowManager classes, but I'm not able to find much in the way of documentation on these classes.

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm describing?

TYIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of future searchers: the answer is to use the WindowManager class.  It's pretty straightforward, despite the lack of documentation (that I could find, anyway):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
// assign position, dimensions, and layout behavior as properties of wlp
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService("window");
wm.addView(someView, wlp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be a RelativeLayout. Position the View where you want it and then set the visibility to gone. The when you want to show the View, start an animation and set the visibility to visible.

A Layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
    <!-- your main UI -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <!-- the UI for the separate component -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the code

```
Animation someAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.some_animation);
hiddenView.startAnimation(someAnimation);
hiddenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The above is easy but not very versatile, to do something more robust means writing a custom View or ViewGroup and good in depth tutorials on such things are unfortunately few and far between.

Comment: as i mentioned it needs to be modular and portable, so pre-supposing a particular layout does not work.  i've have the component built and it works fine, but i'd like to know how to use the Window and WindowManager classes to enable functionality without respect to existing UI.

Comment: Then perhaps this github project that uses a popup window might be of help to you https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction/